# How to give top and bottom different color for rounded borders using css?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, border-radius

I want to place icon with rounded borders with different border color. Linked the image as I want. I designed rounded corners using tailwind css class, I am not getting how to give different border color.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZWJQ.jpg)

Comment: You need to include the code you have tried so far. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Also, the image you have given looks as though the border is a gradient rather than fixed colors. Could you describe exactly what you require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a really simple example using two `div` elements.

```css
.outer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, purple);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inner {
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">F</div>
</div>
<p>Facebook</p>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xsuwv5dk/1/)